# SAP BOE in iFrame - redirects login page

Tags: html, iframe, business-objects

I am embedding the SAP BOE console into an iFrame for our remote users.

To facilitate this, we are using a reverse proxy which works.

BUT, when the page that contains the iFrame is opened, the SAP BOE LOGIN page redirects to a "TOP" container.

According to SAP, by setting the OpenDocuments.properties option (detailed below) should resolve this condition, but not in my case:

```
    Step1: Stop Tomcat or the java application server being used
    Step2: Navigate to the OpenDocument Properties
           - ...\Tomcat\Webapps\BOE\WEB-INF\Config\default
    Step3:  Change below settings
         Logon.allowinsecureEmbedding=false
         to
         Logon.allowinsecureEmbedding=ftrue

    Step4 : Start Tomcat or Java Application server.
```

This is the only setting I have found online referencing this issue. I am wondering that since I am displaying the BOE console, if this is the correct setting? Nothing I have tried yet seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Make the same change in the **BIlaunchpad.properties** file.

The safer way to do this is copy it from :

```
... /tomcat/webapps/BOE/WEB-INF/config/default/
```

to :

```
... /tomcat/webapps/BOE/WEB-INF/config/custom/
```

and to make the change to **BIlaunchpad.properties** in the custom directory.

Comment: It'd be nice if you could add the `why`, as well - Why does this help, and what was the OP missing?